# help getting the title of an anchor tag with jquery

Tags: jquery-validate, anchor, background-image

I think I understand why it's not working. But don't know enough yet to make it work.

First I generate a list using Jquery

```
var imageNumber = 42;
for (imageNumber = 1; imageNumber <= 42; imageNumber++){
  $("#thumbReelList")
    .append('<li><a title="worksImage'
    + imageNumber 
    +'" style="background: no-repeat center url(/worksImages/THMworksImage' 
    + imageNumber 
    + '.jpg)" href="#"></a></li>');
}
```

Then when one of those links is clicked I grab it's title and use that title as the jpg name for the background image of a different DIV.

```
$("#thumbReelList > li > a").click(function(){
  var imageName = $(this).attr("title");
  $("#backgroundImageBox").css({"background-image": "url(/worksImages/"+ imageName +".jpg)"});
});
```

The problem seems to be according to firebug, that when I call this "click" function, at that time Javascript has not yet generated any "title" attribute for the anchors.

When I use an "alert" for the imageName variable it returns NOTHING T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was right so I just switched the titles to IDs and here's the working code

---

```
var imageNumber = 42;
for (imageNumber = 1; imageNumber <= 42; imageNumber++){
  $("#thumbReelList")
    .append('<li><a id="worksImage'
    + imageNumber 
    +'" style="background: no-repeat center url(/worksImages/THMworksImage' 
    + imageNumber 
    + '.jpg)" href="#"></a></li>');
}


$("#thumbReelList > li > a").click(function(){
  //alert("the id of this anchor is = "+ $(this).attr("id") );
  $("#backgroundImageBox").css({"background-image": "url(/worksImages/"+ $(this).attr("id") +".jpg)"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a space is missing before the style attribute in the append function.
Try this:

```
var imageNumber = 42;
for (imageNumber = 1; imageNumber <= 42; imageNumber++){
  $("#thumbReelList")
    .append('<li><a title="worksImage'
    + imageNumber 
    +' " style="background: no-repeat center url(/worksImages/THMworksImage' 
    + imageNumber 
    + '.jpg)" href="#"></a></li>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply but ... no go. I think I found the problem though. I'm using a jquery "tooltip" plugin which looks like it goes through all the tags and erases their "title" attribute so that it can replace it with a cool orriginal tooltip

Comment: Oh.. Good... May be use can use rel attribute of anchor tag to assign the image URL and use it instead of title then.